# Using wildcard characters in SUM function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query in which I would like to sum the areas in one column, based on the value in another column (using wildcard characters).
My data look something like this, before summing the areas:

```
ID              Classification                 Area
--------------------------------------------------------
1                  1-2-0-1                      30
1                  1-2-1-1                      55
1                  1-2-1-1                      15
1                  1-4-0-1                      60
2                  1-2-0-1                      50                      
2                  1-2-0-1                      100
2                  1-4-1-0                      45
2                  1-4-1-1                      35
```

Now I would like to sum the areas partitioned by Classification and ID, which I accomplish doing the following:

```
SELECT
  ID,
  Classification,
  SUM(Area) over (partition by Classification order by ID)

FROM MyTable

WHERE   (Classification LIKE '1-2-%' OR     
        Classification LIKE '1-4-%')
```

which returns

```
ID              Classification                 Area
--------------------------------------------------------
1                  1-2-0-1                      30
1                  1-2-1-1                      70
1                  1-4-0-1                      60
2                  1-2-0-1                      150                      
2                  1-4-1-0                      45
2                  1-4-1-1                      35
```

This works perfectly, when searching for specific (unique) charecters. However, I would like my function to sum all rows which are only similar in the first three characters, to get something like

```
ID              Classification                 Area
--------------------------------------------------------
1                  1-2-%                        100
1                  1-4-%                         60
2                  1-2-%                        150                      
2                  1-4-%                         80
```

Does anyone have an idea how to accomplish this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `left()`:

```
SELECT ID, Classification,
       SUM(Area) over (partition by LEFT(Classification, 3) order by ID)
FROM MyTable
WHERE Classification LIKE '1-2-%' OR     
      Classification LIKE '1-4-%';
```

EDIT:

On second glance, you seem to want the data aggregated and *then* cumulatively summed.  For this:

```
SELECT ID, LEFT(Classification, 3),
       SUM(SUM(Area)) over (partition by LEFT(Classification, 3) order by ID)
FROM MyTable
WHERE Classification LIKE '1-2-%' OR     
      Classification LIKE '1-4-%'
GROUP BY ID, LEFT(Classification, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Beat me to it @Gordon!

```
SELECT * INTO #Test FROM (VALUES
  (1, '1-2-0-1', 30),
  (1, '1-2-1-1', 55),
  (1, '1-2-1-1', 15),
  (1, '1-4-0-1', 60),
  (2, '1-2-0-1', 50),                    
  (2, '1-2-0-1', 100),
  (2, '1-4-1-0', 45),
  (2, '1-4-1-1', 35)) A (Id, Classification,Area)


SELECT DISTINCT Id, LEFT(Classification,3)+'-%' Classification, SUM(Area) OVER (PARTITION BY Id,LEFT(Classification,3)) Sum FROM #Test

Id          Classification Sum
----------- -------------- -----------
1           1-2-%          100
1           1-4-%          60
2           1-2-%          150
2           1-4-%          80
```